# How to regex the class name out of this?

Tags: regex, groovy

So imagine I have big long string and inside it, I have this piece of text....

```
(BlahUtils.loggerName(MyClass.class.getName())
```

I want to extract out "MyClass".

If I do:

```
def matcher1 = test =~ /MyClass/
matcher1[0]
```

I get it. But then MyClass can be anything and that is what I want to extract out.  How do I do that?

Comment: Is the value always followed with `.class`? Is it always alphabetic? Check [this **Groovy demo**](https://ideone.com/q7vfsL), `test =~ /\w+(?=\.class\b)/`

Comment: That's a good start.  But there may be other instances.class in the String so the loggerName( is also important.  I try ```def m = (test =~ /\w+(?=loggerName\(\.class\b)/)
        if (m) {
            println m.group();
        }```  But that doesn't work

Comment: Then `test =~ /(?<=loggerName\()\w+(?=\.class\b)/`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/rcFnfI)

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
/(?<=loggerName\()\w+(?=\.class\b)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YMJ2Ky/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=loggerName\()` - right before, there must be `loggerName(` substring
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?=\.class\b)` - right after, there must be a `.class` as whole word.

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/rcFnfI):

```
String test = "(BlahUtils.loggerName(MyClass.class.getName())"
def m = (test =~ /(?<=loggerName\()\w+(?=\.class\b)/)
if (m) {
    println m.group();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple no-brainer:

```
'(BlahUtils.loggerName(MyClass.class.getName())'.eachMatch( /loggerName\(([^\(\)\.]+)/ ){ println it[ 1 ] }
```

gives `MyClass`